# A condicional if não está obedecendo as regras

Tags: php, codeigniter, lógica

Estou com uma problema aqui na minha galeria, quando eu entro no menu e escolho qual categoria de imagem que eu vou escolher. Ex: Grupo de louvor (sim é um site religioso), ele tem que ir no meu controller e pegar as imagens onde um campo chamado `imagem_opcao` seja igual a `grupo_louvor` e o campo status seja igual a 1.

Veja como estou fazendo:

Minha `view`:

```
<?php
            // pd($imagens);
            foreach ($imagens as $value) {
                if (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "galeria_imagem") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">

                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">

                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                <?php } elseif (isset($value->jeans_status) && $value->jeans_status == 1 && $value->jeans_opcao == "galeria_jeans") { ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/jeans/' . $value->jeans_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->jeans_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/jeans/' . $value->jeans_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->jeans_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->jeans_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>
                <?php } elseif (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "dp_kids") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>


                <?php } elseif (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "dp_senhores") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>

                <?php } elseif (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "dp_senhoras") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>

                <?php } elseif (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "dp_grupo_louvor") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>

                <?php } elseif (isset($value->imagem_status) && $value->imagem_status == 1 && $value->imagem_opcao == "dp_eventos") {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 code">



                        <figure>
                            <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="<?php echo $value->imagem_descricao ?>">
                                <div class="image-hover">
                                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src="<?php echo base_url('tema/assets/img/site/' . $value->imagem_link); ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?>">
                                    <h5 class="margin-top-20"><?php echo $value->imagem_titulo ?></h5>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="overlay">
                            </div>
                        </figure>




                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Agora o meu `controller`:

```
public function showroom($tipo = null) {
        $data = array(
            'titulo' => 'Galeria de imagem'
        );
        switch ($tipo) {
            case 'jeans':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->jeans_imagem->GetAll(false, "jeans_id", 'asc');

                break;
            case 'kids':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');

                break;
            case 'senhores':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');

                break;
            case 'senhoras':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');

                break;
            case 'grupo_louvor':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');

                break;
            case 'eventos':
                $data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');

                break;


            default:
                return FALSE;
        }

        $this->template->load('front/tema_front', 'front/galeria_imagem', $data);
    }
}
```

Mais quando eu seleciono a imagem vem outras imagens que o campo da minha tabela `imagem_opcao`.

Ex.: No meu campo está cadastrado uma imagem e o campo `imagem_opcao` está com o valor kids ai o `if` deixa entrar outras `imagem_opcao` como `dp_senhores`.

Por que o `if` não consegue filtrar o campo `imagem_opcao`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2T6cxuP0

Answer (score 2):

Cara, o if, aparentemente, está ok. Dá uma conferida no banco se a coluna **imagem_opcao** está com tipos diferentes, olha se as imagens estão associadas aos grupos corretos.
Dá um var_dump($imagens) na view e vê se está trazendo os dados da forma que vc esperava.

Comment: Então amigo, eu tenho uma tag options dessa forma:

<option value="dp_senhoras">Departamento Senhoras</option>
<option value="dp_kids">Departamento kids</option>
<option value="galeria_jeans">Departamento jeans</option>

Comment: E é desse jeito que os valores vão para o campo imagem_option

Comment: Hmm, mas vi no seu controller vc fazendo:
`data['imagens'] = $this->imagem->GetAll(false, "imagem_id", 'asc');`,
e os ifs estão comparando com o valor de cada item (`$value`) do array `$imagens`. 
Não entendi como vai usar o valor de uma das options nos ifs. =/

Comment: eu acabei fazendo de outro modo, usando where no controoller e resolveu

Comment: Saquei, blz então.